# In traceroute source code why the size is hard coded to 512 : u_char packet[512];

Tags: linux, icmp, traceroute

In `traceroute` while revising the source code, I saw that the ICMP inbound packet size is hard coded to 512.

I don't know why the size is limited to 512 bytes. What happen if the ICMP inbound packet size is greater than 512 bytes?

Answer (score 0):

In general, there are 3 ways(I am not familiar with implementation using GRE protocol) to implement traceroute, sending ICMP Echo requests, UDP packets or TCP SYN packets with gradually increasing TTL value, starting with TTL value of 1.

- if it sends ICMP echo request, it expects ICMP TIME Exceed message(8 bytes + IP header(20 bytes) + first 8 bytes of original datagram's data) or the destination is reached and returns an ICMP echo reply which is 20 + 8 bytes long. Though according to [rfc 792](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc792), it allows for an arbitrary data length for echo request or reply , but traceroute needn't that.
- if it sends UDP pakcets, it expects ICMP TIME Exceed message or the destination is reached and return a port unreachable message which is 20 + 8 + 20 bytes long. Maybe some implementations add some data, but it wouldn't be too much.
- if it sends TCP SYN packets, the inbound packets should be ICMP TIME Exceed message, TCP SYN+ACK packet or TCP RST packet, all of them are much less than 512 bytes.